# Google Maps SetCenter function refusing to work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Trying to get my SetCenter Function to work but its not.

Here is the code:

```
$("#searchclick").click(function(){

    var address = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var latitude2 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

            var longitude2 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            var relocate = ("(" + latitude2 + ", " + longitude2 + ")");

            alert("setting the center to: " + relocate);

            map.setCenter(relocate);

            } //when status is OK

        }); // geocode

    });
```

the alert correctly returns the following: `setting the center to: (40.7143528, -74.0059731)`

but its not making the center of the map the correct point...

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5):

Set center takes a `google.maps.LatLng` object.  Change your code to:

```
var relocate = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);
alert("setting the center to: " + relocate);
map.setCenter(relocate);
```

See:

[setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

[LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)